# is there a way i can convert an operator as a char "+" into the actual operator for arithmetic?

Tags: c++

How would i convert the char "+" into a + for addition? i'm trying to do something that's has user enter an operator +-*/ then print a operator b.

I could just do a bunch of if statements, but was wondering if there was a way to more efficiently do this?

```
if (operator == "+") {cout << a + b;}
else if (operator == "-") {cout << a - b;}
```

etc..

Comment: For a simple expression parser, it's not going to get much more simpler than that. And simple is good, as it keeps your program maintainable. IMO simple trumps efficient in most cases.

Comment: Declare :`char op;` then use `if(op == '+') { etc }` << That is the basic.

Comment: Is your current solution inefficient? Have you profiled it and determined the "bunch of if statements" to be the bottleneck?

Comment: I hope you know `operator` is a key word.

Comment: Looks like the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to accomplish? Write a LR parser to evaluate expressions? A language interpreter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a switch assuming `token` is a char where you get the operator and `op1` and `op2` are 2 operands:

```
switch (token)
{
    case '/':
        val = op1 / op2;
        break;
    case '*':
        val = op1 * op2;
        break;
    case '+':
        val = op1 + op2;
        break;
    case '-':
        val = op1 - op2;
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a map with function pointers.

```
int addition(int a, int b){
  return a + b;
}

std::map<char, int(*)(int, int)> operators;
operators.insert(make_pair('+', addition));

char c = getch();
int first_operand = 10;
int second_operand = 20;

int result = operators[c](first_operand, second_operand);
```

Comment: Prefer list-initialization wherever possible!

Comment: Or a map of `std::function<T(T,T)>`, and leverage `std::plus<T>` et al.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Not just `std::plus`, rather `std::plus<>` (from C++14) in which case it picks a specialization which is much more generic.

Comment: @Nawaz I edited my comment to make it clear. I wasn't aware of any specializations. It is a class template, so I can't see how it could be used without the `<T>`.

Comment: @juanchopanza Didn't know about `std::plus` et al. Thanks!

Comment: @juanchopanza: `std::plus<T>` is even more bad than simply saying `std::plus<>` which is exactly same as `std::plus<void>` (because `T` defaults to `void`). See [this demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/67ba630ea9d15905) which shows why `std::plus<>` is much more generic. :-)

Comment: @Nawaz OK, when C++14 comes out, I will come back and change my comments :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe using a switch is better in this case. Otherwise the solution seems OK to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map like this too, I don't think the efficiency matters too much in this case.

```
cout << operators[op](a, b);
```