# convert char to arithmetic operator

Tags: c++, char

I have a char stand for an operator,there are four operators(+ - * /) in total.

How i did :

```
int Compute(char c, int a, int b)
{
    if(c == '+')  
        return a+b;
    else if(c == '-')     
        return a-b;
    else if(c == '*')
        return a*b;
    else (c == '/')
        return a/b;
}
```

Is there a more convenient way to do this?

Comment: I think the answer is NO.

Comment: what do you mean by 'more convenient' ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is there a way i can convert an operator as a char "+" into the actual operator for arithmetic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19242330/is-there-a-way-i-can-convert-an-operator-as-a-char-into-the-actual-operator)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a switch statement:

```
int Compute(char c, int a, int b)
{
    switch (c) {  
    case '+': return a+b;
    case '-': return a-b;
    case '*': return a*b;
    case '/': return a/b;
    default: throw std::runtime_error("No such operator");
    }
}
```

Comment: you could add a check for b != 0 in case of division

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the syntax

```
else (a == '/')
    return a/b;
```

is wrong, and should be

```
else if (a == '/')
    return a/b;
```

Secondly, your `a` parameter can only take 4 discrete values, so good practice is to use an enumeration, e.g.

```
enum Operation
{
    kAddition,
    kSubtraction,
    kMultiplication,
    kDivision
};

int Compute(Operation a, int a, int b)
{
    if (a == kAddition)  
        return a+b;
    else if (a == kSubtraction)     
        return a-b;
    else if (a == kMultiplication)
        return a*b;
    else if (a == kDivision)
        return a/b;
}
```

which ensures that the user of `Compute` will only use one of those four values for the operation (`a`) parameter.

I probably haven't used best practices in my example, so I recommend you read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869790/best-practices-for-enum-in-c) for more detail.

Finally you could make the code more concise by using a switch statement:

```
enum Operation
{
    kAddition,
    kSubtraction,
    kMultiplication,
    kDivision
};

int Compute(Operation a, int a, int b)
{
    switch (a)
    {
        case kAddition:
            return a+b;
        case kSubtraction:
            return a-b;
        case kMultiplication:
            return a*b;
        case kDivision:
            return a/b;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Superxy See this tutorial for the correct syntax. http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/

Answer (score 0):

```
int ComputeByChar(char a, int c, int b)
{ 
    switch(a)
    {
    case '+': return c+b; 
    case '-': return c-b;
    case '/': return c/b;
    case '*': return c*b;
    default: cout<< "Invalid";
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this can answer the question, it's better to provide some explanations about how this code help.